# OwnerData TListView leaking memory for Items.Add?

Tags: listview, delphi, memory-leaks

The following code will report memory leak on shutdown for OwnerData TListView:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
    ListView1.Items.Add.Caption := 'blah';
end;
```

I never realized it is forbidden to do regular `Items.Add` in OwnerData mode?

Worse, once added, is memory leak inevitable?

Manual `Free` (for both `Item[0]` and `Items`) causes crash.

Subsequent `ListView1.OwnerData := False` does not solve.

Comment: You never do Items.Add in a virtual list view. That doesn't even make any sense. In a virtual list view, you only tell the control the *number* of items and then write a OnData event handler so the control can ask you about the items.

Comment: Andreas Rejbrand: why not have both "regular" items and ondata handler, and switch dynamically? i would nonetheless expect an error...

Comment: @hundreAd the underlying Win32 ListView control doesn't support that. Either it holds physical items, or it does not. There is no mixing that. And it wouldn't make sense for `TListView` to allocate physical `TListItem`s for virtual items, that defeats the whole purpose of the virtual mode.

Comment: apparently ```ListView1.OwnerData := True;``` removes all the existing items

Comment: Yes, setting `OwnerData = True` is equivalent to saying, "Hey, Mr. List View Control, I don't want you to store any items in your memory. Instead, I'll tell you how many items the list should contain, and every time you need to know anything about the *n*th item (like its caption), just ask me about it!"

Comment: @hundreAd Only the items that the ListView actually knows about. This leaked `TListItem` is not one of them, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I never realized it is forbidden to do regular `Items.Add` in `OwnerData` mode?

It is not strictly *forbidden* per se, but it will simply *fail silently* without any error being reported to you.

`TListView.Items.Add()` *unconditionally* creates a new `TListItem` object and then passes it to the Win32 [`ListView_InsertItem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-listview_insertitem) API as the `LPARAM` for the inserted [`LVITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-lvitemw) item. However, that insert will fail in `OwnerData=True` mode, and `TListView` unfortunately does not check for that condition, so it does not free the `TListItem`, hence the leak.

I would actually consider this to be a bug in `TListView`.  I would have expected it to `raise` an exception when `Items.Add()` (and other related methods) are not allowed.  I guess not.  There is only this warning in the VCL documentation:

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomListView.Items

> Warning: `Items` is **read-only** if the list view is in virtual mode. See `OwnerData` for more details.

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomListView.OwnerData

> ... However, **you must manage the items of a virtual list view using the `OnData`, `OnDataFind`, `OnDataHint`, and `OnDataStateChange` event handlers.** For example, you must explicitly provide a value to a list item's `StateIndex` property if it is to display a check box.
>
> **When creating a virtual list view, you must set the `Count` property for the `Items` to the number of items in the virtual list.**

Meaning, you are not supposed to use `Items.Add()` (and other methods) at all when using `OwnerData=True`.  You are supposed to set the `Items.Count` property to the *number* of items you want to display, and then use the `OnData...` events to provide data for each item whenever the ListView asks you for it.

> Worse, once added, is memory leak inevitable?

Yes, because the `TListItem` is never freed by the VCL, so you would have to free it manually.

> Manual Free (for both Item[0] and Items) causes crash.

Correct, because the leaked `TListItem` is not actually in the `Items` list to begin with.  The *only* valid pointer to the leaked `TListItem` is the one that `Items.Add()` returned to you.

> Subsequent `ListView1.OwnerData := False` does not solve.

Why should it?  The ListView does not know anything about the leaked `TListItem` at that point.

---

**UPDATE:** I have now filed a bug report with Embarcadero about this:

[RSP-41256: Memory leak in TListView when OwnerData=True and Items.Add() is called](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-41256)

Comment: i understand the problem, fully agree as to this being a bug. but since you are is no way prevented from creating this mess, can this be fixed is any way (after this already happened?)

Comment: The only way to fix this is to modify the VCL's source code. If you are NOT using Runtime Packages in your project, you can make a copy of `Vcl.ComCtrls.pas` and add it to your project, and then modify the implementation of `TListItems` to raise an exception or fix the leak as desired.

Comment: this can be salvaged IF the return value of ```ListView1.Items.Add``` is kept, then it can be ```Free```-d later as needed... still bad but at least not entirely irreversible

Comment: No, as much as I like to complain about Embarcadero, it's not fair to call this a "bug", especially given the unambiguous documentation.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand documentation or not, anytime memory is allocated and given to another library to own, but that library doesn't actually take ownership of the memory, then the caller needs to free the memory. That is just basic programming requirements. So, not freeing the `TListItem` when `ListView_InsertItem()` fails is a bug, IMHO, rare as it may happen to be (looking back, this issue in `TListItems` has existed for decades, but people using virtual mode *correctly* won't ever encounter it in practice).